# How to prevent Airflow DAGs from running simultaneously?

Tags: airflow, deadlock

### Here's my use case:

I have two DAGs, DAG A and DAG B.

DAG A runs every 15 min, and DAG B every hour.

They cannot under any circumstances run simultaneously.

If DAG A is currently running and DAG B starts, DAG B needs to wait for DAG A to finish. The opposite is true as well - if DAG B is running, DAG A needs to wait.

I have tried adding an ExternalTaskSensor with a custom function to both DAGs to achieve this behavior but eventually it results in a deadlock. Both DAGs end up waiting for each other.

```py
# In DAG A:

sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(task_id='dag_sensor',
                            external_dag_id='DAG_B',
                            external_task_id=None,
                            dag=dag,
                            check_existence=True,
                            execution_date_fn=get_execution_date,
                            allowed_states=["success", "failed"],
                            mode='reschedule')

def get_execution_date():
    session = settings.Session()
    dr = session.query(DagRun)\
        .filter(DagRun.dag_id == 'DAG_B')\
        .order_by(DagRun.execution_date.desc())\
        .first()
    return dr.execution_date

# DAG B has the same code but finds DAG A's execution date
```

How can I tell one DAG to essentially give up, or yield, to the other DAG if they're waiting for each other?

Answer (score 4):

One option is to set up a [Pool](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/pools.html) containing only one slot, so only one Task is allowed to use that slot at any point in time.

Note that this concurrency limit is at the *task* level, not the *DAG* level, but if you are OK with task execution being potentially interleaved between the two DAGs, then limiting concurrency at the task level is effectively the same.  You can set the `pool` for all tasks in a DAG like so:

```
@dag(
    default_args={
        'pool': 'my_pool',
    }
)
def dag_a():
    ...
```